# Leitura de arquivo texto no C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer uma pequena melhoria em meu algoritmo automatizado no C#, o meu arquivo ".txt" faz a leitura na pasta Entrada de e-mails @empresa.com.br e escreve apenas estes @empresa.com.br em outro arquivo ".txt" na pasta Saida desconsiderando os diferentes, por exemplo: 
email01@empresa.com.br
email02@empresa.com.br
email03@empresa.com.br
email01@teste.com.br
email02@teste.com.br

Acontece que só esta sendo gravado o email03@empresa.com.br mesmo colocando o file.WriteLine(item); O arquivo não esta jogando um em baixo do outro, quebrando a linha, segue meu código:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Entrada\emails.txt");

        int contador = 0;


        foreach (var item in lines)
        {
            if (item.Contains("@empresa.com.br"))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Saida\Resultado.txt"))
                    {
                        if (item != "")
                            file.WriteLine(item);
                    }
            }
            contador++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", contador);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me dar um help nesse ponto?

Abraços.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque está instanciando um novo `StreamWriter` toda vez que vai rodar um loop do seu `foreach`. Apenas jogue para fora assim:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Entrada\emails.txt");

        int contador = 0;


        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Saida\Resultado.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                if (item.Contains("@empresa.com.br"))
                {
                    if (item != "")
                        file.WriteLine(item);
                }
                contador++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", contador);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Victor, não tinha prestado atenção nessa questão do StreamWriter, agora mostra os 3 dados salvos na Saída.

Comment: Que bom Leandro! :D

Comment: :) Vou compartilhar com os colegas para estudo, abraços.